# Flutter - Exact place to put permissions in AndroidManifest file(s) for flutter_reactive_ble library

Tags: android, flutter, manifest

I have problems to manage how to run sample / example codes for **flutter_reactive_ble library** in Flutter mobile app for Android. I have tried few examples, with no luck.

I found that the main reason for errors is lack of provided permissions for Bluetooth. Docs of flutter_reactive_ble library show that we need to put two parts of code to Android Manifest file(s)...

One:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

Two:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" 
                     tools:remove="android:usesPermissionFlags"
                     tools:targetApi="s" />
```

Here are docs for this lib: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble

I don't know where to place them, especially the second part. Without them provided codes won't work.

Another problem is that in Flutter app there are three Manifest files, in three different dirs:

- main
- profile
- debug

Those files are different, which should I edit?

--

Whole Manifest file (from main dir):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" tools:remove="android:usesPermissionFlags" tools:targetApi="s" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <application
        android:label="fl_ble_3"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

The Android Manifest's location is inside `[Project_Root]\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` And your manifest would be look like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.blockchaincommodities.hippo_wallet"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />


   <application>
   ...
   <\application>
<\manifest>
```

As it's mentioned in the document, If you use `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` to determine location, you have to modify the permission and your manifest would be looked like this alternatively:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.blockchaincommodities.hippo_wallet"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" 
                     tools:remove="android:usesPermissionFlags"
                     tools:targetApi="s" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />


   <application>
   ...
   <\application>
<\manifest>
```

Since these permission are critical, You have to ask the user to accept the permissions first. In flutter, you can handle permissions by libraries like [pemission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler). Add this library to your project and add these lines before scanning for devices.

```
PermissionStatus locationPermission = await Permission.location.request();
PermissionStatus bleScan = await Permission.bluetoothScan.request();
PermissionStatus bleConnect = await Permission.bluetoothConnect.request();
```

Comment: OK, but what about second code (I called it "Two")?? I think without it app will not work correctly.

Comment: I still got "Location permission missing (code 3)"

Comment: It's not like you have to use both permissions at the same time. if you want to use the permission to determine the location, you will use the second option

Comment: After your code edit (new answer) - I got: "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: Error parsing /home/siara/StudioProjects/fl_ble_3/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"

Comment: I have to see your manifest. please add it to your question

Comment: I added. Code compiles and runs, but I got "Location permission missing (code 3)"

Comment: I think the problem is since the permissions are critical, you have to request them programmatically before start to scanning, but it isn't mentioned in the documentation and that caused the confusion. check my updated answer

Comment: I will try Your code, after update I will be back here with feedback. Thx.